# What are the best practices for using high-resolution images on a webpage?

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

I'd like to include some high-resolution images on my personal webpage and am curious about what the current practices are to ensure the best possible user experience. I know some practices such as using a CDN help improve load times, but what about ensuring the highest quality viewing experience in all browsers, css fine-tuning, etc.? I'm mostly curious about just serving a single, static background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smaller the file size the better. You want to serve the image as fast as you can by putting it on a CDN or at least on a separate (sub)domain, but if you have optimized content delivery on your end, then ultimately the bottleneck is often the user's connection. Smaller files translate to faster, more responsive load times.

In terms of a background image, are we talking one large image or tiling a smaller image? Either way, try to make the image size as small as you can make it while maintaining the desired image quality. Most image creation/manipulation software has tools that allow you to optimize images for web delivery.

You should also take mobile devices into consideration by utilizing a mobile friendly responsive design, and possibly (depending on the design of your site) using different, smaller images for your small screen style.

Answer (score 0):

Well the first thing you can do is compress the file so that the quality and resolution is preserved while decreasing the size of the file. Using a CDN as mentioned will help immensely.

I would also personally opt for interlaced rendering as opposed to [progressive rendering](http://blog.codinghorror.com/progressive-image-rendering/) for a static background image as it is visually nicer on slower connections.

In addition, you can load a different smaller image based on the users resolution which will ensure good results for all users (especially those on mobile platforms).